# Looking for a better way to test an object's class type

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, scripting-bridge

In using Scripting Bridge with Excel, when I get the value of a single cell, I don't know what class I'm going to get from the cell. A range of a single cell so far returns an `NSString` or `NSNumber` (a range of multiple cells always returns an `NSArray` and I need to coerce the values from there). In my work, I usually only want the *string* value of the cell, so to coerce the value of a single-cell range into what I need, I do this...

```
NSString *cellValue = [targetRange.value get];
if ([cellValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    cellValue = [targetRange.value get];
} else if ([cellValue isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    cellValue = [[targetRange.value get] stringValue];
}
```

My problem lies with the first line (we'll ignore the third line for the time being as I'm still doing a bit of refactoring). Would there be a better class to capture the value of the cell to test for class against? Those last three lines work fine, but I don't feel entirely comfortable doing that; it seems unintuitive but going with `NSObject` feels just as weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it seems unintuitive but going with `NSObject` feels just as weird.

In such cases you can use [`id`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW3):

> The id type is completely nonrestrictive. By itself, it yields no information about an object, except that it is an object.

E.g.:

```
id cellValue = [targetRange.value get];
NSString *stringValue = nil;
if ([cellValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    stringValue = cellValue;
} else if ([cellValue isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    stringValue = [cellValue stringValue];
}
```

Note that in your case you could probably just use something like this:

```
NSString *stringValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [targetRange.value get]];
```

Comment: I think I tried `id` but without wrapping my brain around it long enough to fully understand what I was doing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking if it's "okay" or "normal" to inspect an object's class at runtime and act differently depending on the class? If so, that's an emphatic *yes* - that's part of what makes Objective-C so powerful.

If you're asking if there's a better way of determining an object's class, then no, not really. I mean you can directly compare classes ( == ) but that's not always wise, given class clusters, subclasses, etc.

Comment: So you were asking none of the above. :-D